# File to import not found or unreadable: SCSS

Tags: css, angular

I am building an angular application. While trying to import style scss files, I am getting compile error:

> File to import not found or unreadable: layout/menu.

My folder structure is:

```
Insurance\src\shared\styles.scss
```

and for a scss file that I want to include inside the styles.scss is:

```
Insurance\src\shared\styles\layout\_menu.scss
```

Inside styles.scss I have written:

```
@import "layout/menu";
```

in my angulaar.json file I have mentioned:

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/shared/styles.scss"
        ],
```

However, when I compile the code it gives the following error:

```
@import "layout/menu";
 ^
  File to import not found or unreadable: layout/menu.
  in Insurance\Insurance\src\shared\styles.scss 
  File to import not found or unreadable: layout/menu.
```

Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: try `@import "./styles/layout/_menu"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "styles" a folder within "shared"? If so, you want to say

```
@import "/styles/layout/menu";
```

Otherwise it won't know to look in the styles folder

Comment: thanks a lot. Didnt know it would be such a silly mistake I am doing. Thanks a lot.